# Setting /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_no_pmtu_disc to 2 packet still fragmentation not happening

Tags: tcp, mtu

i have set /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_no_pmtu_disc to 2

Path MTU discovery value   Meaning
IP_PMTUDISC_WANT           Use per-route settings.
IP_PMTUDISC_DONT           Never do Path MTU Discovery.
IP_PMTUDISC_DO             Always do Path MTU Discovery.
IP_PMTUDISC_PROBE          Set DF but ignore Path MTU.

now when i have set mtu to 400 and send 1000 bytes via simple client server code , i don't see fragmentation in tcpdump , what can be the issue here?